# Alfresco - How to add more options in a radio button dynamically?

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti

```
public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        execution.setVariable("radio_button_id", "Option 1");
        execution.setVariable("radio_button_id", "Option 2");
        execution.setVariable("radio_button_id", "Option 3");
}
```

I want to add Option 1, 2 and 3 and set id option_1, option_2 and option_3 respectively. And should look like this

[image]

This was my java code. However it didn't work.
Need help on how to add more options in radio button dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Basically , UI customization can not be done at java side.You need to customize share forms.

Please check below link for same.This link contains the workflow form configuration,for existing workflows.

https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/share/src/main/resources/alfresco/share-workflow-form-config.xml

below is the link for customizing the form control.You need to write your own JavaScript logic for your dynamic control.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/forms-custom-formcontrol.html